# what is the nginx equivalent command apache has for a2enmod?

Tags: apache2, webserver, nginx, ssl, mod-rewrite

I'm following this guide: [How to Setup OwnCloud Server 5 with SSL Connection](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/04/how-to-setup-owncloud-server-5-with-ssl-connection.html)

Problem though is that the guide is for apache but I am using nginx for my server. As such I am trying to "reverse engineer" the instructions to use them for nginx.

The step I am having most problems with is:
`a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers && a2enmod ssl`

What is the a2enmod apache command equivalent for nginx?

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent.  Nginx modules must be selected during compile, run-time selection of modules is not currently supported.

A full summary of the compile-time options, including optional modules, can be found in the provided configure script by running `./configure --help` <sup>[Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)</sup>

For more information about see [Nginx Modules](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules)